# Upload Data After App is Closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, offline

I have a pretty unique situation:

My iOS app has companion hardware that it's connected to via Wi-Fi. The Wi-Fi creates a local network, meaning that when the phone is connected, there is no outside internet access.

I want to be able to post analytics up to a centralized server that we've built via a simple REST API. The issue is that users may only ever open and close the app while they're connected to the network, meaning that when they do have outside internet access, the app may have been terminated (or at the very least, put in the background).

If I run code inside of

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive(UIApplication *)application
OR
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
OR
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

They may only get called when the user is still connected to the Wi-Fi network with no outside access.

Is there any way you can think of uploading some simple data to our server even under these circumstances? Is there a way to spin up a quick background process to do this after the fact?

Thanks!

Comment: hey AlexKoren, did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSURLSession` to do uploads from the background. Once you submit the upload task, the system keeps it running even if your app moves to the background or is terminated.

Comment: And what happens if the app is connected to the Wi-Fi when it is terminated? Do I have to somehow retry to the request? Or will it be marked dirty and retry it (unlikely, but I'll ask anyway!)?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I believe the system will handle the loss of connection and start/resume the connection when the network connection is reestablished. (Unless it hard fails while connected to your no-internet WiFi.)